# Database for upvotes and downvotes

Tags: sql, database

If I have a database with for an article and I have a field for upvotes.
I was thinking about creating an SQL Query with which I will first get the current value of upvotes and then I will increment 1 to the value

But what if 5 people at once click on the upvote button what will happen then?

or is there a better way to do this altogether *

Comment: To get some inspiration, you might want to look at SEDE: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new (although the model has been altered for the data dump)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My strong suggestion is to keep a record of every upvote and downvote in a `votes` table:

```
create table votes (
    votes_id <autoincrement> primary key,
    user_id int references users(user_id),  -- whodunnit
    topic_id int references topics(topic_id),  -- what they're voting on
    inc int,
    created_at datetime default current_datetime,
    check (inc in (-1, 1))
);
```

You can then summarize the votes as you want.  You can see trends in voting over time.  You can ensure that someone can "unvote" if they have voted in the past.

And, inserting into a table runs no risk of having different users interfere with each other.

The downside is that summarizing the results takes a bit more time.  You can optimize that when the issue arises.

Answer (score 4):

There are two solutions:

1. If you really need to load the value into your application and increment it there, writing it back afterwards, get an appropriate lock on the table before selecting the value. Release the lock after you finished with the value. Either because of cancellation or rewriting an actual upvote.

   Otherwise a concurrent instance *B* could have read the same value and write it back after the first instance *A*. Say both read *3*. Both increment it to *4*. Then *A* writes it back before *B*, the value in the database is *4*, *B* the also writes it back and again the value in the database is *4*. Though *3+2=5*. So one upvote would get "lost" this way. It's called a "lost update problem".

   You can prevent this with a lock as mentioned. As *B* cannot read from the table before you've updated and released the lock. Afterwards it will read *4* instead of *3* and therefore write back *5*, which is correct.
2. But preferably, do it in a single update, like

   ```
   UDPATE votes
          SET votes = votes + 1
          WHERE article = @some_id;
   ```

   That is, you increment the actual value in the database, regardless of what your application thinks this value currently is.

   Provided that your transaction has an appropriate isolation level the database will take care of locking by itself and thus keep concurrent transaction from updating with "dirty", outdated data.

I suggest, you read a little more about transactions, isolation levels and locking to fully understand the problem.